# Using sed in shell function to automate compiling and running F# code

Tags: shell, sed

I'm trying to make a bash script to quickly compile and run F# code from my terminal. Normally, the way you'd go about doing it if you had a file named `myCode.fsx` is to run the following command:

```
fsharpc myCode.fsx && mono myCode.exe
```

I've tried to write a little function in shell to help, that takes as its first and only argument the filename (including `.fsx`) of the code. But I think I'm having some trouble with the `Sed` command. This is my code, which compiles the `.fsx`-file fine at first, but then I think `Sed` goes in and changes the text in the just created `myCode.exe`-file instead of just changing the file extension in the terminal command to be run:

```
function fsx {
    fsharpc "$1" && mono | sed 's/fsx/exe/' "$1"
}
```

How would I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it the way you started it, you need [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) and something like a [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) instead of a pipe:

```
fsx() {
    fsharpc "$1" && mono "$(sed 's/fsx$/exe/' <<< "$1")"
}
```

I've anchored `fsx` at the end of the string, just to avoid problems should a filename contain `fsx` elsewhere.

However, you can do it without external tools, just with [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
fsx() {
    fsharpc "$1" && mono "${1%fsx}exe"
}
```

`${1%fsx}` removes `fsx` from the end of `$1`, end the `exe` is simply appended.

Notice that I used `fsx()` instead of `function fsx`; the former is understood by all POSIX shells, the latter is a Bashism.

If you do use Bash, there's another parameter expansion that expresses "replace pattern at the end of a string" a bit more closely:

```
"${1/%fsx/exe}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the second approach works like a charm. Simple and effective answer.